# python timezone problem with the same timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, pytz

Why I get different result timezone in the one file with the almost same datetime constructions?

```
print(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')))
>>> 2020-05-31 12:55:04.778210+03:00

print(datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 12, 54, 0, 0,  pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')))
>>> 2020-05-31 12:54:00+02:30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies within the fact that `pytz` uses a different time zone model than the Python standard lib. [Here's a blog post by Paul Ganssle](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) explaining the issue.

The correct way to do this with `pytz` would be to use the `localize` method of its `timezone` class:

```
import datetime
import pytz
print(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')))
>>> 2020-05-31 15:15:45.559007+03:00

print(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow').localize(datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 15, 16, 0, 0)))
>>> 2020-05-31 15:16:00+03:00
```

While `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))` correctly creates a `datetime` object with the defined timezone, `datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 12, 54, 0, 0,  pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))` creates a naive `datetime` object first and then `replace` the timezone. Avoid `replace` when working with `pytz`, use `localize` instead.

An alternative to `pytz` is [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Here, the above operation is more straight forward since `dateutil` uses the standard lib's time zone model:

```
import dateutil

print(datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Moscow')))
>>> 2020-05-31 15:13:55.967773+03:00

print(datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 15, 14, 0, 0,  dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Moscow')))
>>> 2020-05-31 15:14:00+03:00
```